# preg match all with static string at beginning of pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am putting together a preg match all in PHP with the following string:

```
{{beginning_of_string|:|optional_param|:|http_link}} 
{{beginning_of_string|:|optional_param|:|text}} 
{{beginning_of_string}}
```

All three of these possibilities can occur in the overall string, or just a single occurrence.  Here is my regex so far:

```
preg_match_all('#\{\{beginning_of_string(.+?)\}\}#', $content, $string)
```

So far this only matches the first two occurrences of the string, and not the last one.  This regex matches just the last occurrence:

```
#\{\{beginning_of_string\}\}#
```

I'm fairly new to regex so I know it is probably something simple.  Anyone have any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` means "one or more repetitions".

You need `*` for "zero or more repetitions":

```
preg_match_all('#\{\{beginning_of_string(.*?)\}\}#', $content, $string)
```

Comment: Hahaha I knew it!  Thanks Tim.